# syncronize passkeys between different computers with Win 11 OS, with the same Microsoft account

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-11, password-management, credentials

So I've created a porkbun.com account using an email and a passkey as my credential. I did it on Win 11 Huawei laptop with fingerprint scanner and Win Hello enabled.
I'm using my fingerprint scan to log into Win 11 on that Huawei laptop.

[image]

At different apartment I have a different computer. Dell OptiPlex 3060 Workstation. But Win 11 Pro is there and I'm using the same Microsoft account to log into this machine, but not a Windows Hello method, simply because there's no fingerprints scanner on this computer. Therefore I'm logging in traditionally, using login and password. But I'm 100% sure I'm using the same Microsoft Account to log into both of these computers.

The next thing I remember is that. when I've created this porkbun passkey, Windows asked me to scan my fingerprint, which I did. Therefore I assume this passkey is somehow connected not only with my Windows Account, but also with my fingerprint scan.

How to syncronize the passkeys from my Huawei laptop into my OptiPlex 3060 workstation, so I can log into my porkbun.com from that second computer and manage my domains?

This is how it looks like, when I try 2 login to porkbun.com from this second computer, the OptiPlex 3060, where I don't have these porkbun credentials.

[image]

---

```
       E D I T
```

---

As @Ramhound wrote in a comment below and I've confirmed [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2023/06/23/how-to-use-and-manage-passkeys-in-windows-11/),
the Passkey that was created is stored securely on my computer (which in my case means Huawei laptop with fingerprint scanner), and is available across browsers in Windows 11.
It is not transmitted to the website, and since a password is not involved in the authentication process, Passkeys are resistant to phishing attacks. They mention nothing about passkeys synchronization between different computers, belonging to the same person.

Comment: Windows Hello authentication is device specific.  If Passkey you configured requires Windows Hello, in order to authenticate with the Passkey, then you must setup Windows Hello on both devices.

Comment: I understand this. But the problem is that on my Huawei laptop my Windows Hello authentication is fingerprint scan and on my Dell OptiPlex 3060 Workstation, Windows Hello authentication is PIN. Therefore I don't understand how the passkey created on a laptop with a fingerprint scanner can be synced or recreated on a computer, where I use PIN to authenticate via Windows Hello; Because there simply isn't a fingerprint scanner on my Dell OptiPlex 3060 Workstation.

Comment: Sorry; Passkey management feature within Windows does not synchronize between devices. However, that feature, is currently only in an Insider Preview build. Windows Hello authentication also is device specific. Synchronization is easy, 1Password, supports Passkey storage now.

Comment: [Passkey sync on Windows](https://www.corbado.com/blog/passkeys-windows-11) as of January 2024 still requires a non-Microsoft third party solution - Bitwarden, Dashlane, 1Password, etc